# Strange artifacts in mesh

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, objects

These beakers look fine in wire frame but they show odd shadows in solid view that persist when the scene is rendered. How do I fix this?

[image][image][image: Rendered]

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQSzlIf4gF6M1VlSGZzSUl5SXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @cegaton Maybe, but I didn't realize that there were overlapping faces

Comment: duplicated/overlapping geometry will cause what is called Z-Fighting, basically the render engine gets confused on what face is supposed to be rendered when they occupy the same space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have duplicated the mesh without moving it. Try selecting all vertices in edit mode and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the specials menu and selecting *remove doubles*. You may also want to recalculate your normals after doing this from the shading/UVs tab on the toolshelf of the 3D View.

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems. Unfortunately, you will have to address them individually across all the meshes or address them once, delete the other meshes, and duplicate the one 'cured' one.

### Problem 1

As mentioned by HowToBlend, you need to key *W* and select *Remove Doubles*.

### Problem 2

Your normals are wrong, so your shading is, too. While still in edit mode, use *A* once or twice to select the whole mesh, go to the *Tools* bar and further to the *Shading/UVs* tab. Under *Shading > Normals:*, click *Recalculate*. This will fix the majority of the normals issue, but there is still more.

### Problem 3

Select shading *Flat* in object mode. Return to edit mode and select these faces:

[image]

I would advise you to make use of *Alt + RightMouseKey* and *Shift + Alt + RightMouseKey* to select the face loops. Anyway, with these selected, again return to *Tools > Shading > Normals:*, but this time click *Flip Direction*. The last of the weird black color should dissipate. Go to object mode and select *Smooth* once again.